Failed to connect to GitHub Codespace in Visual Studio Code: "exception was thrown by handler: exception failed to start vs code remote server"
I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to a GitHub Codespace using Visual Studio Code. The error message that pops up is:
enter image description here
I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Checked for updates to Visual Studio Code, but it says that I'm using the latest version.
--Disabled all extensions to see if any of them were causing the issue.
--Reset VS Code settings by deleting the settings.json file.
--Tried connecting to different codespaces, but the issue persists.
--Checked GitHub Status, but there are no ongoing issues reported.
--I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to fix it?
